# Memory usage of face detector not released

Tags: ios, profiler, nsautoreleasepool, cifacefeature

I'm using the iOS face detector on all possible orientations of an image like this

```
for (exif = 1; exif <= 8 ; exif++)
{
    @autoreleasepool {


    NSNumber *orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:exif];
    NSDictionary *imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
    NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    glFlush();
    features = [self.detector featuresInImage:ciimage options:imageOptions];
    //features = [self.detector featuresInImage:ciimage];

    if (features.count > 0)
    {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-I- found faces using exif %d",exif];
        [faceDetection log:str];
        NSTimeInterval duration = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - start;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-I- facedetection total runtime is %f s",duration];
        [faceDetection log:str];
        self.exif=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:exif];
        break;
    }
    else {
        features = nil;   
    }
    }

}
```

but it seems in the profiler that the memory is growing each time:

Not sure if this is true, and if so how to solve the issue

[image: Sorted by overall bytes and still living]

[image: Detail of the category]

[image: The relevant code]

Answer (score 0):

In your loop most of the objects are auto-release type the main issue seems to be that you are assigning new value to "features" in each loop and if the "if" statement is true you are not making it nil. Try doing this:

```
if(features.count > 0)
{
  /// your existing code here
  features = nil;
  break;

}
```

Comment: I'm doing features= nil; before the return statement but still getting the memory usage

Comment: oh I see.... From your code it looks like that were doing it only in else statement. However, it would be better to do it in the end of if-statement as return won't be called until for loop is executing.